# "wget --convert-links" rewrites anchor-only links; can I prevent it from doing that?

Tags: regex, wget

If you use `wget --recursive --convert-links` (`wget -r -k`) to download an HTML page from `http://example.com/index.html` which contains this text:

```
<a href="#anchor">one</a>
<a href="http://example.com/index.html">two</a>
```

wget will rewrite the links to look like this:

```
<a href="index.html#anchor">one</a>
<a href="index.html">two</a>
```

I would prefer wget *not* to rewrite that first link, since `"#anchor"` is a perfectly valid way of referring to the destination anchor on the current page — so there's no *technical* reason for it to change the spelling of that link, as far as I'm aware.

Is there any way to convince wget not to rewrite anchor-only links like that one?

If not, can you think of any automated/mechanical way to "un-rewrite" them? (I can `wget -r`, git commit, `wget -rk`, git diff, and then manually fix up the unwanted diffs... but "manually fix up" is tedious. Another option is "Just don't care because it's not important"; I'm already considering that solution as well. :))

Comment: I think you mean `--convert-links` rather than `--fix-links`

Comment: @Aaron: Oops. Fixed!

Comment: It's ugly and not efficient, but you should be able to use this to perform mass replacements : `find . -name '*.htm*' -exec bash -c 'sed -i.bak "s/href=\"$(basename "{}")#/href=\"#/g" "{}"' \;`

Comment: It iterates over htm/html files in the current directory and its child directories and executes the following sed command for each of them : `sed 's/href="<filename>#/href="#/g'`, replacing links that refer to the file itself and contain an anchor by the anchor alone. It's made ugly by the fact that it needs the basename of the file, but that this command must be executed after `find` has replaced the `{}` by the name of the file, so we need to use `bash -c` to delay the expansion of the `$(basename)` subshell. It's inneficient because it needs to execute one `sed` command per file.

Comment: @Aaron: Consider turning that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty nor efficient but you could use the following :

```
find . -name '*.htm*' -exec bash -c 'sed -i.bak "s/href=\"$(basename "{}")#/href=\"#/g" "{}"' \;
```

The `find` selects every htm[l] file in your current directory and its subdirectories, then executes the following `sed` command for each of them :

```
sed 's/href="<filename>#/href="#/g'
```

This `sed` command targets `href` attributes that start with the file's name followed by an anchor and remove the filename from them, achieving your purpose.

We need to add a layer of indirection with `bash -c` in the command we ask `find` to execute because otherwise the `$(basename "{}")` subshell would be interpreted before `find` replaces the `{}` by the file's name, which would make us search the path of the file relative to your current directory rather than its name.